# Need solution for the error 'Invalid JSON text: "Invalid escape character in string."' in nodejs when updating mysql record with object value

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-update

```
let sql: string = 'UPDATE  queryList SET ';
  const sqlUpdates: string[] = [];
  if (config && config.queryId && config.configJson) {        
    sqlUpdates.push(`configJson = '${JSON.stringify(config.configJson || {})}'`);
  }
  if (config && config.queryId && config.queryName) {
    sqlUpdates.push(`queryName = '${config.queryName}'`);
  }
  if (sqlUpdates && sqlUpdates.length) {
    sql += sqlUpdates.join(',');
  }

  sql += `  WHERE queryId = '${config.queryId}'`;
  const [rows, fields] = await myDb.query(sql, []);
```

the above lines of code is in nodejs, trying to update the query. properties that sending from payload from ui is

```
  configJson: {filePath: "D:\Users\AVenka22\slash"}
  queryId: "4b978290-b052-449c-81b5-0759e187db5e"
  queryName: "slashTest"
```

After execution i'm getting this error

```
  Invalid JSON text: \"Invalid escape character in string.\" at position 15 in value for column 'queryList.configJson'.
```

Comment: You most likely need to double the backslashes. Or better, use prepared statements instead of "building" the SQL.

Comment: i tried using replace method to replace backslashes but still got same issue. can you suggest me the code correction

Comment: Better, use prepared statements instead of "building" the SQL.

Comment: Sure will try that and update the result. Tq salman